# Android SQLite Contraint Conflict. Try/Catch couldn't catch

Tags: android, sqlite, try-catch, constraints

```
08-02 16:26:24.750: E/Database(28841): Error inserting data
08-02 16:26:24.750: E/Database(28841): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
08-02 16:26:24.750: E/Database(28841):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_execute(Native Method)
08-02 16:26:24.750: E/Database(28841):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.execute(SQLiteStatement.java:61)
08-02 16:26:24.750: E/Database(28841):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1584)
08-02 16:26:24.750: E/Database(28841):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1428)
08-02 16:26:24.750: E/Database(28841):  at com.app.android.DataOperations.insertItems(DataOperations.java:69)
08-02 16:26:24.750: E/Database(28841):  at com.app.android.DownloadTask.createDatabase(DownloadTask.java:173)
08-02 16:26:24.750: E/Database(28841):  at com.app.android.DownloadTask.doInBackground(DownloadTask.java:59)
08-02 16:26:24.750: E/Database(28841):  at com.app.android.DownloadTask.doInBackground(DownloadTask.java:1)
08-02 16:26:24.750: E/Database(28841):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
08-02 16:26:24.750: E/Database(28841):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
08-02 16:26:24.750: E/Database(28841):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
08-02 16:26:24.750: E/Database(28841):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
08-02 16:26:24.750: E/Database(28841):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
08-02 16:26:24.750: E/Database(28841):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Above is my LogCat report. What I am trying to do is to insert data. After looking at the logcat I found that it is a constraint violation. I tried to put my code as:

```
public void insert(...){
            long insertID = 0;
            try{
                Log.i("DataOperation", String.valueOf(insertID));
                insertID = sqllitedb.insert(DBase.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
            }catch(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException ex){
                Log.i("dataops_", "Error Constraint"); //Print
            }

}
```

Nothing is happening.. My logcat is full of stacktraces. No Sign of the line with comment(see above).

How can it be handled. 
N.B. There is only one insert satements(which is above) in my whole program. Test Ok then I will proceed.

Also tell me how to handle whether my database is created/already exists so that if exists I will not run my DownloadTask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException` instead of a `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException`

If this doesn't work, try and catch any exception with `Exception` to see if the catch block is being called.

Comment: SQLiteConstraintException is a subclass of SQLiteException, so the OP shouldn't need to change that.

Comment: I considered that, that's why I got him to try just `Exception`

Comment: Yeh I tried the both way. Initially I was using android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException, next I used Exception and now SQLiteException.

Comment: Try debugging and stepping through your code, you might be able to see what's going wrong a bit better that way...

Answer (score 11):

Maybe `insert(..)` method catch exceptions itself.

use `insertOrThrow(..)` method instead.

```
    try {
        SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteHelper.getDatabase();
        db.insertOrThrow(Table, nullColumnHack, values);
    } catch (SQLiteConstraintException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "failure to insert word,", e);
        return false;
    }
```